# Best cloud solution for an AI that makes and posts YouTube videos

Tags: webserver, youtube, cloud, hosting, google-cloud-platform

I want to make an artificial intelligence that produces (generate script, TTS, edit and render) videos on its own and post to YouTube, all automatic. Just as a fun experiment.

But I need help to know the best cloud solution for this, I went to Google Cloud Platform to get an idea. But I want my AI to maybe use an editing software (like Vegas, Premiere), I might need a virtual machine, but I'm not sure which cloud solution can be used instead of the virtual machine. I don't even know if a VM is really needed for this.

I don't want to pay for something expensive that could be done in a different and cheaper way, also it doesn't need to be hosted with GCP. I just want to know what type of solution I should use no matter the platform.

I really don't know anything about server types and etc. Please help me.
By the way, any feedback about this experiment is welcome.

(If it helps) my inspiration came from these videos:

- [Video 1](https://youtube.com/watch?v=kjhu1LEmRpY) (Brazilian Portuguese)
- [Video 2](https://youtube.com/watch?v=WwY9hszV7oQ&t) (English)

Keep in mind that I don't want to exactly replicate what they did, it's just for reference.

Comment: I think you'll need to do a bit more research.

Comment: Software recommendations are offtopic

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> I need help to know the best cloud solution for this.

I would argue that the answer is the one you choose to use.

None of your requirements (generating a script, text-to-speech, editing and rendering video) likely requires more than the command line and the power of a standard desktop PC. Something like GCP would probably be fine, but a simple raw VPS (or set of VPS servers) would probably be fine, too.

> I just want to know what type of solution I should use no matter the platform.

Again, there is likely no "universal" solution, as different platforms offer different things.

That said, a good platform likely will be able to run the [Python scripting language](https://www.python.org/). It has well-supported AI modules, has modules to render text-to-speech from Google (for free or in conjunction with higher quality GCP voices) or e.g. Amazon Polly and can invoke programs like [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) for editing or rendering video from the command line. [YouTube even has an overview of uploading videos via Python and its Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video).